# How to start system services like init.d in linux on AWS using userdata

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04

I will be starting the server(ubuntu) every day in the morning and will stop at night, this is a daily task. All I wanted to do is just to bring up the services after the server restarts the next morning. 
I used to add the script to "user data" in aws, but it din't help me. can you please do let me know if I need to run a different command using user data.what would the script look like. 
I used '

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo service <service name> start
```

Comment: Any reason you aren't simply configuring the service in Ubuntu to start on boot? https://askubuntu.com/questions/9382/how-can-i-configure-a-service-to-run-at-startup

Comment: the server is already configured, all I wanted is to start the service ,when the server restarts the next day. so that I dont have to go in and manually restart the service.

Comment: It sounds like the server isn't fully "configured" if it isn't starting critical services on boot.

Comment: the server have a service in init.d, usually when ever we are deploying new code to it, we will stop the service , and the copy the code, and then we will restart the service manually. but as the servers are restarted every day in the morning ,some one needs to start the service. so I wanted to see if we can start the service when server restarts every time

Comment: I don't see how any of that is relevant to the fact that you could just configure the service to automatically start on boot, and it would work exactly as you want, instead of trying to hack together some service starting script with user-data.

Comment: @MarkB Hi Sorry  I understood your answer now, than when the question was posted, I did used rc.local to start the services when the instances reboots or restarts or start. Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default user data is executed once, at the first boot of the instance. Here is a similar question: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/execute-user-data-ec2/

If you need to automatically restart the service but the instance has been configured. You could use `mime-multipart` to append your new scripts to user data and set the cloud_final_modules as `[scripts-user, always]` to run the startup script everytime. You could set following as your user data and then start the instance:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="//"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--//
Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config.txt"

#cloud-config
cloud_final_modules:
- [scripts-user, always]

--//
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="userdata.txt"

#!/bin/bash
sudo service abc DEV start
--//
```

Comment: I dont have any idea of this Mime-multipart,  if you dont mind can you give me a juust brief of what this code is doing, as I see cloud-config.txt and userdata.txt , also should I be using every thing same or should I edit any of your provided code

Comment: You could edit the last second line `/bin/echo "sudo service abc DEV start" >> /etc/rc.local`, or you can try to change to `sudo service abc DEV start` to see if it always run the command after restart.

Comment: do I need to use only last two lines of code, or the entire code that you provided. I am asking this because I dont have a knowledge about mime-multipart. also would like to know what are the two .txt I am seeing in the code, Thanks

Comment: Just edited my answer. You need everything. `[scripts-user, always]` is to always run your script.

Comment: Hi Thanks it did worked, but it would be more helpful if you can give me a brief insite of how this code worked. so I can make implementation of similar things in future .

Comment: Then could you mark the answer as accepted to let others know the solution? Using a MIME multipart file, you can specify more than one type of data like the text/cloud-config and text/x-shellscript in the example. You could refer http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AmazonLinuxAMIBasics.html .   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit

Comment: Hi Liu, can you let me know what is this line doing "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config.txt"" and Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="userdata.txt" . I am checking online but it seems there is a lot in depth, that i should know. but rather it would be better if you can let me know in brief. Also are these files,we store some where on server. thank you.

Comment: `Content-Disposition` Headers defines the presentation styles for MIME body parts:,  either `INLINE` or `ATTACHMENT`. The `filename` parameter if the file for storing the bodypart. You can find the two created files in `/var/lib/cloud/instance`. If you check your `/var/log/cloud-init.log` you will find `Oct 03 21:36:38 cloud-init[2424]: __init__.py[DEBUG]: {'Content-Transfer-Encoding': '7bit', 'Content-Type': 'text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"', 'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="cloud-config.txt"', 'MIME-Version': '1.0'}`

Comment: Hi Kai Lui, I wanted to use this script to run a script on the server. example:- when server starts there is a script called aptcontrl.sh at the location /home/ubuntu/jasper/./aptcontl.sh start . can you direct me if I have to use a different method. thank you so much for your time.